# Android - Parcel: unable to marshal value

Tags: android, parcelable, parcel

I'm trying to pass data through activities with Parcelable. This is my code :

```
public class Player implements Parcelable {

public static final Parcelable.Creator<Player> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Player>() {
    public Player createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new Player(in);
    }

    public Player[] newArray(int size) {
        return new Player[size];
    }
};
private String name;
private List<Card> listCards;

public Player(String namePlayer) {
    name = namePlayer;
    listCards = new ArrayList<>();
}

private Player(Parcel in) {
    // This order must match the order in writeToParcel()
    name = in.readString();
    in.readList(listCards, null);
    // Continue doing this for the rest of your member data
}

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeString(name);
    dest.writeList(listCards);
}
```

Whenever I run this code, I get the error :

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcel: unable to marshal value com.antoinedelia.lebarbu_versionalcool.Card@ec54bb
```

Do you have any idea what could be the problem?

Thanks

Comment: Card is a separate class? Does that implement `Parcelable`?

Comment: Card is indeed a separate class, but it does not implement Parcelable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
  dest.writeString(name);
  dest.writeList(listCards);
}
```

Since `Card` class does not implement `Parcelable` you cannot do `writeList/readList`. It is only applicable for List of `Parcelable` Objects.

Comment: It isn't only applicable to Parcelable, just it falls back to writing Parcelable if it is no other type of Object that can be Parcel-ed

Comment: @cricket_007 Serializable will also work in `writeToParcel` ?

Comment: `writeList` loops over all objects and does `writeValue(Object)` - The list can be found here https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcel.html#writeValue(java.lang.Object)