# Parcel: unable to marshal value

Tags: android, kotlin, anko

I'm using Kotlin with Anko and I want to send to another activity a list of Players.

```
class Player(var name: String?) {
var score: Int = 0

init {
    this.score = 0
 }
}
```

My activity:

```
 class MainActivity: AppCompatActivity() {
         override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle ? ) {
             btn.setOnClickListener {
                 val players = ArrayList <Player> ()
                 players.add(Player("John"))
                 players.add(Player("Jeff"))

                 startActivity <ScoreActivity> ("key" to players)
             }
         }
 }
```

When the code reaches the startActivity line, I get this error:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcel: unable to marshal value
>   com.yasin.myapp.Player@4e3940e

I suppose something is wrong with my class Player, but I don't know what. I'm using kotlin version 1.1.4. Someone can help me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android - Parcel: unable to marshal value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37862017/android-parcel-unable-to-marshal-value)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your class should implement `Parcelable` (or `Serializable`, though `Parcelable` is the advised one on Android) to be able to pass the objects across Activity using the Intent.

Using Kotlin 1.1.4 and [Android Extensions Plugin](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/android-plugin.html#using-kotlin-android-extensions), you can add `@Parcelize` annotation to get the `Parcelable` implementation.

```
@Parcelize
class Player(var name: String?) : Parcelable {

// ...
```

Refer the [blog post](https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2017/08/kotlin-1-1-4-is-out/).

This feature is covered as experimental, so you have turn on an experimental flag in your build.gradle file:

```
androidExtensions {
    experimental = true
}
```

Another option is to use [this plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/8086-parcelable-code-generator-for-kotlin-) to generate the boilerplate code necessary for the `Parcelable` implementation, but you should remember to update the implementation code everytime you change any properties in the class.

Or you can write your own `Parcelable` implementation.

Answer (score 7):

For anyone working with `jetpack-compose` this problem is due to `rememberSavable()`, use `remember()` or store the value in a viewModel

Answer (score 1):

Your class need to be `Parcelable` or `Serializable`.  There is a [jet-brains plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/8086-parcelable-code-generator-for-kotlin-) you can use to generate an implementation (or you can use an experimental feature `Parcelize`).

`Serializable` is usually less complex, and may be all that you need.

Answer (score 0):

Using Java Just Your Class should implement Parcelable and whit method : 
writeToParcel(Parcel parcel, int i)